# Python gives wrong result with .seconds attribute of timedelta data

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, date, datetime

```
>>>print(today - date, (today - date).seconds)

[1] 63 days, 8:45:34.250649 31534
                              ↑
```

This is far away from the right result. 31534 seconds are much less than 63 days. Why is python giving the wrong value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only requesting the `seconds` of the `timedelta` - you need **[the `timedelta.total_seconds()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds)** method.

The `timedelta.seconds` attribute only reports the seconds from the last day of the delta.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds

```
import datetime

d1 = datetime.datetime.now()

d2 = datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=1.4)

delta = d1-d2

print(delta, delta.seconds, delta.total_seconds(), sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
1 day, 9:35:59.999997
34559  # (9 * 60 + 35 ) * 60 + 59 ca. 34559 - the full day is not part of ".seconds" 
120959.999997
```